# Less stuffy word for *opine*

Tags: single-word-requests

I need another word for *opine*.  *Express the opinion that* is too many characters.  (I have tight space constraints.)  *Opine* sounds too stuffy to me.

Example:

> The expert witness acknowledged the provision was added, but ***expressed the opinion*** that it would not solve the problem.

("Solve the problem" is understandable in the context.)

Comment: Since space is at a premium, what would be wrong with *said*?

Comment: Or *thought*....

Comment: She was making a prediction.  In the present tense it would be "But I don't think that's going to solve the problem."  She didn't have a crystal ball -- she was a psychologist giving her opinion.  So in the third person past tense, I would say "She didn't think that would solve the problem."

Comment: 'agreed that the provision had been added but not that it would be effective/solve the problem,'?

Answer (score 2):

[*deem*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/deem) would work as well:

> Although the expert witness acknowledged the addition, she deemed it insufficient.

Comment: Please see comment below question.

Answer (score -1):

Sorry, I seem to have benefited from the rubber duck phenomenon.

> Although the expert witness acknowledged the addition, she considered it insufficient.

Comment: Rubber duck phenomenon? I googled and got [_all kinds of_  stuff](https://www.google.com/search?q=rubber+duck+phenomenon&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b&gfe_rd=cr&ei=mtleWN74Gcba8genqISABg), none of which seem to pertain.

Comment: @Cascabel - Sorry.  I wasn't sure actually how to say that concisely.  (I forgot that here on ELU I don't need to be concise!)  I'm talking about rubber duck debugging, where you explain your problem to a rubber duck, that you sit on the desk in front of you because you can't find a person to walk your problem through to, and then the solution comes to you.